# What is this "Unknown Name" JSException in Internet Exlorer 6?

Tags: java, javascript, applet, jsobject

I am using JSObject to invoke a Javascript function from my Applet.

SSCCE of my Applet:

```
package ch.vrag.web;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.security.AllPermission;
import java.security.CodeSource;
import java.security.PermissionCollection;
import java.security.Permissions;
import java.security.Policy;

import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class Sscce extends Applet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5403444704039831864L;

public void init() {
    try {
        Policy.setPolicy(new Policy() {
            Permissions perms = new Permissions();

            public PermissionCollection getPermissions(CodeSource codesource) throws SecurityException {
                AllPermission grant = null;
                grant = new AllPermission();
                perms.add(grant);
                return perms;
            }

            public void refresh() {
                // Do nothing
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

    JSObject window = JSObject.getWindow(this);

    JSObject phoneNums = (JSObject) window.eval("getWindowRectangle()");

    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;

    if (phoneNums.getSlot(0) instanceof Integer) {
        x = (Integer) phoneNums.getSlot(0);
        y = (Integer) phoneNums.getSlot(1);
        width = (Integer) phoneNums.getSlot(2);
        height = (Integer) phoneNums.getSlot(3);
    }
    else if (phoneNums.getSlot(0) instanceof Double) {
        x = ((Double) phoneNums.getSlot(0)).intValue();
        y = ((Double) phoneNums.getSlot(1)).intValue();
        width = ((Double) phoneNums.getSlot(2)).intValue();
        height = ((Double) phoneNums.getSlot(3)).intValue();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("x: " + x + " y: " + y + " width: " + width + " height: " + height);

};
}
```

An SSCCE of my HTML File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getWindowRectangle(){

            var winX = (document.all)?window.screenLeft-2:window.screenX;
            var winY = (document.all)?window.screenTop-2:window.screenY;

            var winWidth = (document.all)?document.documentElement.offsetWidth+4:window.outerWidth;
            var winHeight = (document.all)?document.documentElement.offsetHeight+4:window.outerHeight;

            return([winX,winY,winWidth,winHeight]);
        }       
    </script>

    <title>SSCCE</title>
</head>
<body>
    this is an SSCCE
    <APPLET CODE="ch.vrag.web.Sscce.class" name="SSCCE" codebase="scripts" archive="Sscce.jar" width=0 height=0 MAYSCRIPT >
    </APPLET>
</body>
```

This works great exept in Internet Explorer 6. There I have this Java Exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: netscape.javascript.JSException: Unknown Name
```

what is this Exception good for? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: So your company is supporting the 7.1%? [IE6 countdown](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)

Comment: @epascarello not our company does support it... our customer -.- and yes it's annoying...

Comment: I hope you do the +150% cost adjustment to support it and if your customer supports it, your company supports it. :) I sure hope they look at their logs and see that .1% of people use that browser. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Internet Explorer 6 seems to have a Problem with the `getSlot()` command, but I could use a Workaround.

with this Object:
`JSObject phoneNums = (JSObject) window.eval("getWindowRectangle()");`

I can get a String out of phoneNumbs (`phoneNums.toString();`) this String gives me my return values in this form:

> "number1,number2,number3,number4"

so I can split the string and get the numbers I need.

The moral of the story is, that Internet Exlorer 6 is not no contemporary and should not be used any more!

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the browser not being to run Javascript properly. Make sure IE6 is patched to the SV3 version and Javascript is enabled along with the security setting possible.

Comment: It's Sv2 ... and you think that it could be that?

Comment: @Neifen Seeing how you need to test it on IE6, you need all the help you can get. It is possible IE6 doesn't even support those specific Javascript functions either.

Comment: the javascript function are not the problem, the problem is the `getSlot` I think... but I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of [Read/Write HTML field values from Java](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0177.html) is the fine print:

> For best result, never use LiveConnect JSObject in Applet's init() method.

The reason being it is commonly `null` at that point.  I've had more success obtaining a reference to the `JSObject` in the applet `start()` method.

---

```
JSObject phoneNums = (JSObject) window.eval("getWindowRectangle()");
```

I suspect this should be [`JSObject.call("getWindowRectangle()")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/LiveConnect/LiveConnect_Reference/JSObject#call) instead.  Do some debugging on the returned `Object`, inspect it in a debugger to check the content is as you expect.

Comment: same error. I tried to comment code lines out to see where the error is and I did have no error anymore, when i commented the line the `getSlot()` commands out in the Applet...

Comment: hmm it's not better... but when I trace the attribute `phoneNums`I get "123,322,2135,342" (invented Numbers) so I think I could split it instead of making that `getSlot()`thing...